# mapDispatchToProps type challenge (typescript react-redux)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, mapdispatchtoprops

I am not able to figure out the type of my mapDispatchToProps. Check below in the SignInComponent `const mapDispatchToProps`.
Seems simple as the functions takes signIn() as a parameter, from whom type I have availble. However I was not able to figure that out.

This is my autAction.ts:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import { Dispatch } from 'react';

type AuthAction = {
  type: string,
  err?: unknown
}

export const signIn = (credentials: {email:string, password:string}) => {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch<AuthAction>) => {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      credentials.email,
      credentials.password
    ).then(() => {
      dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS'})
    }).catch((err) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_ERROR', err})
    });
  }
}
```

And this is my SignIn component:

```
import React, { BaseSyntheticEvent, Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { signIn } from '../../store/actions/authActions';


type IConnectedDispatch = {
  signIn: typeof signIn
}

interface IMyComponentProps {
  signIn: (credentials: {email:string, password:string}) => void;
}

class SignIn extends Component<IMyComponentProps> {
  state = {
    email:'',
    password:''
  }

  handleChange = (e:BaseSyntheticEvent) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = (e:BaseSyntheticEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log(this.state);
    this.props.signIn(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="white">
          <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Sing In</h5>
          <div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <button className="btn pink lighten-1 z-depth-0">Login</button>
          </div>
        </form> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}

type AuthAction = {
  type:string,
  err?: unknown
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any): IConnectedDispatch  => { //TYPE CHALLENGE HERE. 
  return {
    signIn: (credentials:{ email:string, password:string}) => dispatch(signIn(credentials))
  }
}

export default connect<React.FunctionComponent>(null,mapDispatchToProps)(SignIn)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown in @liamgbs' answer, your `mapDispatchToProps` isn't really necessary, but I do want to answer your questions regarding the typescript issues.

`mapDispatchToProps` is a function which takes `dispatch` as an argument and returns a keyed object of props.  So the type is essentially `(dispatch: Dispatch)`.

The question is *which* `Dispatch` definition to use here, as multiple packages have their own typings for it.  The more basic definitions of `Dispatch` from `react` and `redux` expect that `dispatch` will only be called with a plain action object.  The return value from your `signIn` action creator is instead a function of `dispatch` (a "thunk").  So you need to use typings from the `redux-thunk` package.

`{signIn: typeof signIn}` is also not quite right because you are *calling* `signIn` rather than just returning it. The actual interface is your `IMyComponentProps`, where `signIn` is a `void` function.

```
import { ThunkDispatch } from "redux-thunk";

interface LoginCredentials {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

interface IMyComponentProps {
  signIn: (credentials: LoginCredentials) => void;
}

const mapDispatchToProps = ( dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any, never, AuthAction> ): IMyComponentProps => {
  return {
    signIn: (credentials: LoginCredentials) => dispatch(signIn(credentials))
  };
};
```

Annoyingly, `ThunkDispatch` requires you to set all three generics.  That first `any` represents the type of your redux state, so you could replace that with an actual type if you want.  The `never` is the extra args in your action creator which you aren't using.

Comment: very nice answer, that was the explanation I was looking for. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
import React, { BaseSyntheticEvent, Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { signIn } from '../../store/actions/authActions';

interface IMyComponentProps {
  signIn: typeof signIn
}

class SignIn extends Component<IMyComponentProps> {
  state = {
    email:'',
    password:''
  }

  handleChange = (e:BaseSyntheticEvent) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = (e:BaseSyntheticEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log(this.state);
    this.props.signIn(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="white">
          <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Sing In</h5>
          <div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <button className="btn pink lighten-1 z-depth-0">Login</button>
          </div>
        </form> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(null, { signIn } )(SignIn)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I know I can do that, and `const mapDispatchToProps = { 
  signIn
};` but I would like to figure our the dispatch type, and what am I missing as the type that the `dispatch`is taking in the argument is clear...